# How to backup and delete first message in the queue using Shell Script in IBM MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq

I need to backup the queue and delete the first message in the queue. I have used the below code

`./qload -m qmgr SYSTEM.CLUSTER.TRANSMIT.QUEUE -r 1`

Also I need to display first message has been deleted

Comment: Do you want to display the content of the first message that is being deleted via the command above?  Also can you confirm the command, I think you are missing a `-I` (capital I to delete from the queue) or `-i` (lower case i to browse from the queue).  The output of the qload command will show that one message was read and written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.It works for me

`qload -m $qmgr  -I $qname -f <qmgr>_<qname>_<date>.log -r 1`